# Substring after substring in NSString

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsstring, substring

I am new in objective and I'm facing my first problem, and I can not continue my first project.

it's quite simple, I have a NSString :

```
NSString *myString = @"<font face='Helvetica' size=25 color='#d79198'> Here is some text !</font>";
```

what I want to do is to get the value of the size "25" which is always 2 char long, so I can calculate my UILabel size.

i know how to detect if there is the substring I am looking for "size=" using :

```
if ([string rangeOfString:@"bla"].location == NSNotFound)
```

but I have not found or not understand how to extract the string @"size=XX" and then get the XX as a NSString from *myString

Thank for any help.

Comment: Just generally speaking, you could use a "regular expression", or you could use componentsSeparatedByString.  With the latter you may need to examine each resulting "component" with hasPrefix to find the one that begins "size=".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSString *myString = @"<font face='Helvetica' size=25 color='#d79198'> Here is some text !</font>";
NSRange range = [myString rangeOfString:@"size="];
if (range.location != NSNotFound)
{
    NSLog(@"Found \"size=\" at %d", range.location);
    NSString *sizeString = [myString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(range.location+5, 2)];
    NSLog(@"sizeString: %@", sizeString);
}
```

This should do the trick. You could also at the end do this: `int sizeFont = [sizeString intValue];`

Comment: Note that rangeOfString returns length==0 if the target string is not found. So checking for length is better than location. If the receiver is nil, the length and location are both returned as 0, not NSNotFound.

Answer (score 2):

```
NSString *myString = @"<font face='Helvetica' size=25 color='#d79198'> Here is some text !</font>";
    if ([myString rangeOfString:@"size"].location != NSNotFound)
    {
        myString = [myString substringFromIndex:[myString rangeOfString:@"size"].location]; 
        myString = [myString substringToIndex:[myString rangeOfString:@" "].location]; // Now , myString ---> size=25 color='#d79198'> Here is some text !</font> 
        myString = [myString substringFromIndex:[myString length]-2];// Now, myString ---> size=25
        NSLog(@"myString -- %@",myString); // Now, myString ---> 25
    }
```

Comment: Just as if you were trying to [parse HTML using regular expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454). You **shall not.**

Comment: @H2CO3 hmm... regular expressions... * looking guilty *

Answer (score 1):

If you have string like stack:overflow then use it as follow :

```
 NSString *Base=@"stack:overflow"
 NSString *one  = [[Base componentsSeparatedByString:@":"] objectAtIndex:0];
 NSString *two  = [[Base componentsSeparatedByString:@":"] objectAtIndex:1];
```

In this case one = stack and two=overflow

Answer (score 0):

Part of an HTML page? Then [use the tool that is designed for the task](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: What's wrong with this answer? This is the **only correct answer** so far.

Comment: Non i use this because of colored UILabel

Answer (score 0):

You could calculate the range of the number yourself or use a very simple regular expression to get the substring, something like

```
(?<=size\=)\d*
```

This means that you are searching for digits (`\d*`) that is preceded by "size=" (`(?<=size\=)`)

Which using NSRegularExpression would be

```
NSError *error = NULL;
NSRegularExpression *regex = 
  [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"(?<=size\\=)\\d*" 
                                            options:0 
                                              error:&error];
NSTextCheckingResult *match = 
  [regex firstMatchInString:myString 
                    options:0 
                      range:NSMakeRange(0, [myString length])];
NSString *sizeText = [myString substringWithRange:match.range];
```

Finally you should convert the text `"25"` into a number using

```
NSInteger size = [sizeText integerValue];
```

Comment: First time i use NSRegularExpression, thanks for the tip David.

Answer (score -1):

Use `componentsSeparatedByString:` method...

```
NSString *myString = @"<font face='Helvetica' size=25 color='#d79198'> Here is some text !</font>";
    NSString *theSizeString = [[[[myString componentsSeparatedByString:@" "] objectAtIndex:2] componentsSeparatedByString:@"="] objectAtIndex:1];
    NSLog(@"The sizestring:%@",theSizeString);
```

I  think it will be helpful to you.

Answer (score -1):

You can get the range of the string `@"size="`. The range has location and length. So what you need next is to call on the `myString` the `substringWithRange:` method. The parameter would be an `NSRage` starting from the location+length of `@"size="` and length of 2.